# Undefined Element displayed with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, undefined, undefined-behavior

I am able to display the sum value of 6 DOM elements with a "line_cost" tag name- this is displayed as a sub-total(seen as "ST" methods). Unfortunately, while dynamically calculating the delivery-cost using the sub-total values, I consistently get "undefined" as a value being displayed under the delivery-cost tab while sub-total works perfectly. 
I thought to believe the problem was occurring due to the DOM not fully loading before the method was called, yet even with the decision `if(document.getElementById("sub_total") != null)`, I still achieve an 'undefined' value. What could be the problem for this 'undefined' value occurring?

```
function calcST()
{
    var i;
    var sum = 0; // initialize the sum
    let p = document.getElementsByTagName("line_cost");

    for (i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    {
        if (!isNaN(Number(p[i].innerHTML)))
        {
            sum = Number(sum + Number(p[i].innerHTML)); // p[i].innerHTML gives you the value
        }    
    }

    setST(sum, "sub_total");
}    

function setST(sum, item_id)
{
    let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
    i.innerHTML = sum;
    calcDelivCharge();
}    

function getST()
{
    if (document.getElementById("sub_total") != null)
    {
        let i = document.getElementById("sub_total");
        let v = i.innerHTML;
        return v;
    }
}    

function calcDelivCharge()
{    
    var delCharge;
    var e = getST();

    if (e < 100)
    {
        delcharge = e*0.10
    }
    else
    {
        delcharge = 0;
    }

    setDelivCharge("delivery_charge", delCharge);
}

function setDelivCharge(item_id, delCharge)
{
    let i = document.getElementById(item_id);
    i.innerHTML = delCharge;
    calculateTAX();
}    

function getDelivCharge()
{
    let i = document.getElementById("delivery_charge");
    let v = i.innerHTML;
    return v;
}
```

Comment: which variable is coming up as undefined?

Comment: The delivery cost variable(delCharge). I edited my question to reflect this.